# How to wire a Woods PRO 59104 Timer

Tags: wiring, timer

I'm running an irrigation pump on 240V circuit I added to my breaker panel, and it's working fine with just a switch between them.  After my first attempt to add the timer between the switch and the panel failed (kept tripping the breaker when I turned the timer to "on"), I'm hoping to get some direction here.
  I have the wiring diagram attached.  It appears to indicate the 2 wires from the breaker go to screws 2 and 4, while there's a jumper between 3 and what I'll call 0, the un-numbered screw.  Then 0 and 1 run down the line to the 2-pole shut-off switch by the pond.  Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! Your wiring diagram did not attach. Can you edit your question to provide a link to it or a link to a picture of it?

Comment: When the switch  is "on", it connects 1 and 2.  Separately on the other pole, it connects 3 and 4. Now the timer needs power itself, and that power must be always-hot (on at all times).  That must be supplied between 0 and 1.  Rather than trying to wire the whole shebang at once, try hooking up only 0 and 1, and see if the timer then runs.

Answer (score 1):

### You have it backwards

While I can't explain the breaker trips in your setup, the [documentation for your timer](http://waterheatertimer.org/pdf/Woods-59101_59103_59104-timer.pdf) has the line in going to 0 (with the jumper to 3) and 1, with the load (the wires to the shutoff) connected to 2 and 4.  The way you have it wired won't work anyway, as the motor would be powered through the timer contacts, which would cause the timer to not time 99% of the time.